# How to format(bold) only the authors part of in text citation using apacite package

Tags: citing, apacite

I am using apacite package to format a report. At the moment using the `\cite{key}` command for the in text citation it appears as (Author, year), however I want to change the Author name labels to bold.

I have skimmed through the customize section of the package documentation, but could not find how to achieve it. So my question is how can I customize the formatting of author names-(change it to bold)?

My latex code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\title{latex MWE}
\author{Imran}
\begin{document}
\cite{bib:Apriori}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

In the `reference.bib` file I have the following entry:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{bib:Apriori,
  author =       "Agrawal Rakesh and Srikant Ramakrishnan",
  title =        "Fast algorithms for mining association rules",
  booktitle =    "VLDB'94, Proceedings of 20th International Conference on Very
                  Large Data Bases",
  year =         "1994",
  PAGES =        "487-499"
}
```

And the output is

[image]

The desired output would be to have the Author's name to appear as:

(**Rakesh & Ramakrishnan**, 1994)

**Update:**

The Customization section (6) of the apacite manual mentions `\BAstyle` that can be used to change the style of the authors' part of in text citation, but I don't know how to use it to correctly achieve the desired result. I have tried `\renewcommand{\BAstyle}{\scshape}` which does what the documentation says, but `\renewcommand{\BAstyle}{\textbf}` doesn't work.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\BAstyle}{\bfseries}`?

Comment: @moewe your suggestion solved the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already identified `\BAstyle` yourself, but you can't use a macro such as `\textbf` for it, you need to use a switch

```
\renewcommand{\BAstyle}{\bfseries}
```