# Bold format just the references in an APA annotated bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I've been asked to make the references bold so they stand out from the annotations. In [this documentation](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) I see plenty of punctuation commands I can change using `\renewcommand`. The closest I've gotten is the following, based on [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391398/how-to-formatbold-only-the-authors-part-of-in-text-citation-using-apacite-pack):

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\bfseries}

\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apacann}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

```
% main.bib
@string{ NIPS = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems}}

@article{attn_all_you_need,
  author = {Ashish Vaswani and
      Noam Shazeer and
      Niki Parmar and
      Jakob Uszkoreit and
      Llion Jones and
      Aidan N. Gomez and
      Lukasz Kaiser and
      Illia Polosukhin},
  title = {Attention Is All You Need},
  journal = NIPS,
  volume = {30},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need},
  urldate = {Nov 19, 2019},
  annotate = {This is a test.}
}
```

Again, what I need is for the entire reference to be bold except for "This is a test." If someone could point me to the right command to renew, I would be on my way!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for including a minimal document with your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look unbelievably awful and I don't recommend it, but if you're forced to do it the following will do the trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@string{ NIPS = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems}}

@article{attn_all_you_need,
  author = {Ashish Vaswani and
      Noam Shazeer and
      Niki Parmar and
      Jakob Uszkoreit and
      Llion Jones and
      Aidan N. Gomez and
      Lukasz Kaiser and
      Illia Polosukhin},
  title = {Attention Is All You Need},
  journal = NIPS,
  volume = {30},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need},
  urldate = {Nov 19, 2019},
  annotate = {This is a test.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\bibitem}{\bfseries}{}{}
\pretocmd{\APACrefannotation}{\normalfont}{}{}

\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apacann}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I know it looks awful, but this is for a class... Thanks so much!